# Dual Column Layout in CSS with dynamic height in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a dual column layout using CSS:

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="left_column"></div>
<div id="right_column"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>

#left_column{
    float: left;
    width: 463px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 12px;    
}

#right_column{
    float: right;
    width: 463px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin-right: 12px;
}

#footer{ 
  clear:both;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

This works fine in Firefox, but creates problems in IE.  The main problem is that the content of these two columns is dynamic and never amounts to the same height with either column sometimes having a bigger height than the other.  In IE, the left and right columns align with the bottom which creates a variable amount of space between the shorter column and the nav.  What I would like is to have the columns align with the top/nav and then when an element is inserted with ajax at the top of the left_column, it just pushes the content in that column down and the two columns remained aligned at the top.  I hope that made sense, any help is appreciated.

...

Using igoogle layout as an example, I have added the following css and it seems to be working:

```
<div id="outside">
    <div id="left_column"></div>
    <div id="right_column"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

#outside{
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}

.column {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

I have yet to fully implement it, but this seems to be aligning the columns with the top regardless of height and expands/contracts with the top as a reference point.

Comment: Do you have an example online of what is currently happening?

Comment: In what version of IE? it seems to work fine on my IE8. It's worth pointing out that inline-block is not valid CSS, which might be causing problems.

Comment: inline-block is valid CSS2. It's not supported well in IE6/7 though.

Comment: It is valid CSS2.1, which is a candidate recommendation, but it is not valid CSS2.0, which as I understand it is currently still the "standard", whatever all that means. But whatever, it's not going to work in older browsers.

Comment: Yea, I am not using inline-block for IE.  I am trying to work for IE6 and IE7 but care mostly about 7.  I am unable to show an example online, but an example of this working online is on igoogle.com.  The three columns align with the top and when a gadget is minimized the other gadgets shift up to fill that space.

Comment: I have added the css that seems to be working above, not sure what has helped specifically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this resource will be of help to you:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Since you want to have only 2 columns, 
have a look at the given example here:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm

Kind regards, mtness.